# reset network to its defaults

Tags: 14.04, network-manager, reset

I don't know how but i had messed up with some installations. At present my Data-card doesn't detects under mobile broadband but can be seen while executing 'lsusb'. Is there a way to reset the network manager to its defaults without complete re-installation of the OS?  Is there a solution using live CD? I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3):

Open Terminal and type these commands:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Now edit the file:

```
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback
inface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Now save that file.

After this step you have to open another file via terminal.

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

After doing this editing job. Run this final command :

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And then restart your Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 16.04:
open **/etc/network/interfaces**

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

edit contents to

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

In this case the directory **/etc/network/interfaces.d** should be empty.